# How to use pipe separated values in a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets

I have data coming in from a survey and one of the questions asks which social media platforms they use. The form is connected to google sheets and when multiple options are selected, the form adds them to the same cell with a pipe separator.

| Social media |
| --- |
| Instagram , Facebook , Tiktok , Snapchat |
| Instagram , Snapchat |
| Facebook , Tiktok , Snapchat |

(I've used comma separators here for formatting reasons)

When I create a pivot table, it see's each of these cells as distinct values. I'm trying to aggregate a count for each unique social media platform. There is also an other text field entry so not all values are known.

I used this formula

```
=transpose(ArrayFormula( QUERY( UNIQUE( TRIM( FLATTEN( SPLIT(AD2:AD,"|")))),"where Col1 is not null order by Col1")))
```

To create columns of all unique values and then used this formula on each row to return a true or false if the user selected that value.

```
=if(BJ$1<>"", iferror(find(BJ$1,$AD2),-1)>=0,"")
```

But the pivot table now see's each of these columns as a different field when I need to be one (Social media).

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. We can't assume your desired output. You may use below formula to filter unique values to column. Then use pivot table for your final output.

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),", ")))),"where Col1 is not null")
```

You can also use `pivot` clause to make it pivot report.

[image]